# How to write a currency converter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I search for all parts in a text that contain € or EUR or another currency to convert it to another currency of my choice?

Ie:

1. How do I isolate the number left or right of a € or EUR or another currency sign?
2. How do I replace that very number with the changed value?
3. How do I apply this to all numbers of the webpage that have the € or EUR or another currency sign before or after?

Comment: I think the better way here is to present a dropdown for your users to select currency, and leave the nominal field to just integer. But your call (or your client's) anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code to search a text for any currencies and convert to a target currency:

```
var currencies = {
    "EUR": ["€", "EUR", "EURO", "EUROS"],
    "USD": ["$", "USD", "USDOLLAR", "USDOLLARS"],
    "DEM": ["DEM", "DM", "Deutsche Mark"]
};
var rates = {
    "EUR": { USD: 1.2613, DEM: 1.96 },
    "USD": { EUR: 0.792832792, DEM: 1.54315 },
    "DEM": { USD: 0.648121, EUR: 0.51 }
};
function currencyReplacer(number, sourceCurrency, targetCurrency, currencyFormatIndex, currencySeparator) {
    var c, i, comma = /,/g;
    for (c in currencies) {
        if (currencies.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            for (i = 0; i < currencies[c].length; i++) {
                if (currencies[c][i] === sourceCurrency) {
                    console.log(rates[c][targetCurrency], number);
                    return [Math.round(rates[c][targetCurrency] * number.replace(comma, "."), 2), currencies[targetCurrency][currencyFormatIndex || 0]].join(currencySeparator || "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
function replaceCurrencies(text, sourceCurrency, targetCurrency, currencyFormatIndex, currencySeparator) {
    var prefixedRegex = new RegExp("(" + currencies[sourceCurrency].join("|") + ")\\s?(\\d+(?:(?:,|.)\\d+)?)", "gi");
    var suffixedRegex = new RegExp("(\\d+(?:(?:,|.)\\d+)?)\\s?(" + currencies[sourceCurrency].join("|") + ")", "gi");
    return text.replace(prefixedRegex, function(m, currency, number) {
        return currencyReplacer(number, currency, targetCurrency, currencyFormatIndex, currencySeparator);
    }).replace(suffixedRegex, function(m, number, currency) {
        return currencyReplacer(number, currency, targetCurrency, currencyFormatIndex, currencySeparator);
    });
}
replaceCurrencies("This function will convert currencies: €50 is less than 100 EUR which is more than 75 €", "EUR", "DEM", 1, " ");
// will output: "This function will convert currencies: 98 DM is less than 196 DM which is more than 147 DM"
```

Could this solve your problem?

**Edit:** Updated the code above to include your wanted target currency DEM, and made the regex/replacer support both prefixes and suffixes and also a sourceCurrency

**Edit2:** Updated the code again to handle decimal numbers

Comment: Please excuse my non-sense test string

Comment: Alright, so I included your version here: http://pastebin.com/15RjnZCp It turns out to not replace the values...

Comment: The regex i supplied in the code will only match when the number of euros is in front of the euro sign. If you need to match instances typed like this: €50, use this regex instead:
`var regex = /(€|EURO?S?)\s*(\d+)/gi;` 
If you need to match both 50€ and €50 the code will have to be rewritten to support both those regexes/cases.

Comment: Yes I need 50€ and €50 and 50 € and € 50 and 50EUR and EUR50 and 50 EUR and EUR 50

Comment: Make sure the rates are up to date. They should be in the format `/*one*/ EUR: { /*is*/ DEM: 1.96 }`

Comment: using your updated version leads to something like "699,00 €" being converted to "699,0 DM".

Comment: You must have done something wrong when using the code. If you copy and paste my example into a JavaScript console, you get the output as shown in the code comment.

Comment: How would you iterate through the site? You see my approach at http://pastebin.com/15RjnZCp Is there a way to feed the whole site to the function - is it advisable performance-wise? I found my iteration to not access some elements that were present in the site. I am using opera.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer to handle decimal numbers. You could iterate all div-s on a page using this code:
`Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), function(elm) { 
    elm.innerHTML = replaceCurrencies(elm.innerHTML, "EUR", "DEM", 1, " ");
})`

Comment: This is what I have: http://pastebin.com/41EPUTHy If you use it with amazon.de you still see EUR instead of DM. Try it yourself.

Comment: My code does currently not handle thousand-separators, and i also noticed it has a bug where it does not care about what comes after a possible decimal separator. You should read up on, and learn regular expressions and fix the code yourself, because any further work on the supplied script would urge me to charge you for the work. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There is just no way to find out in a text if a currency is really used.

For example, how can you differentiate these:

- The € currency is fine
- We need 50 € (EUR)
- Is different than 50€
- And same for $
- Which can be used like this $50
- Or like this $ 50
- Or even like this 50$ (by europeans)

But I'll let you handle this part.

If you have a string that *you know* it's a currency, you can play this way:

```
// Find out what's the currency used
if ( /[$]/.test( str ) ) // Currency is $
else if ( /[€]/.test( str ) ) // Currency is €

// etc. To get the number out of this string, use:
var val = /\d+/.exec( str ); // if "str === 50$", it returns "50"
```